# blueprint css - select tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, blueprint-css

Currently working on rails 3.

I made changes in my css file to add a width of 330px to the size of the select drop-down menu by making the following changes:

```
select {
   width: 330px;
{
```

The problem is, there is another page I want to have drop-down menus using the select tag where I want the width to be 230px.  I tried adding a class to the select tag but it didn't work:

```
select.ul-item {
   width: 230px;
{
```

This is the view page where I want the drop-down menu to be 230px.

```
<ul>
  <li><%= select_tag(:gender, options_for_select(['Male', 'Female', 'Unisex'])) %></li>
  <li><%= select_tag(:age_range, options_for_select(['Birth-12 Mos.', '12-24 Mos.', '2 Years', '3-4 Years', '5-7 Years', '8-11 Years', '12+ Years'])) %></li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE ONE**

This is what is on the page source:

```
  <div class="span-6">

<ul>
  <li><select id="gender" name="gender"><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option><option value="Unisex">Unisex</option></select></li>
  <li><select id="age_range" name="age_range"><option value="Birth-12 Mos.">Birth-12 Mos.</option><option value="12-24 Mos.">12-24 Mos.</option><option value="2 Years">2 Years</option><option value="3-4 Years">3-4 Years</option><option value="5-7 Years">5-7 Years</option><option value="8-11 Years">8-11 Years</option><option value="12+ Years">12+ Years</option></select></li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE TWO - SOLVED**

Oddly enough, what actually worked is this:

```
#gender, #age_range {width: 230px}
```

I don't understand why it works without the selector but it works. Who knew.  Thanks for helping on the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oddly enough, what actually worked is this:

```
#gender, #age_range {width: 230px}
```

I don't understand why it works without the selector but it works. Who knew. Thanks for helping on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector:

```
select.ul-item
```

is looking for a `select` tag with a class of `ul-item`

No where in your HTML is there a select tag with that class. That's the problem.

Comment: Oops sorry, typo on my part.  The ul-item was actually there.  I put the class with the <ul>, <li>, <div> and nothing worked.  I guess if there is a way to label a select_tag with a class, I don't know how to do it. Please let me know if I should be putting the ul-item class somewhere in the select_tag

Comment: the class item can go wherever. You just have to make sure your css selector matches the DOM structure for it to find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select#gender, select#age_range{
  width: 230px;
}
```

Comment: Can you view source and show me the html of that particular select section?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the selector as powerful as possible.

```
body div.span-6 ul li select#gender,
body div.span-6 ul li select#age_range {
  width: 230px;
}
```

Or try adding `!important` to the width property.